# Finding the index wise maximum values of two lists

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have 2 lists:

```
L1 = [2,4,1,6]
L2 = [1,5,2,3]
```

The output should be a new list that contains the biggest numbers found in L1 or L2 based on their position.

Example output:

```
L3 = [2, 5, 2, 6]
```

How to do it ?

Comment: How have you tried to do it, and what's going wrong?

Comment: Input?  Or Output?  How about the example code that you've tried and the reason it does not work for you??

Comment: I'll start you out with [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1663807). Add a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the `max()` function and you'll have a solution in just one line.

Answer (score 10):

One of the possible solutions is to zip your lists, and then applying max operation element-wise, which can be obtained in python through call to functional `map`

```
L1 = [2,4,1,6]
L2 = [1,5,2,3]
L3 = map(max, zip(L1, L2)) # python2
L3 = list(map(max, zip(L1, L2))) # python3
```

or more pythonic through list comprehensions

```
L3 = [max(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in zip(L1, L2)]
```

or a bit shorter version using unpacking operation

```
L3 = [max(*l) for l in zip(L1, L2)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) in a list comprehension:

```
>>> L1 = [2,4,1,6]
>>> L2 = [1,5,2,3]
>>> [*map(max, zip(L1, L2))]
[2, 5, 2, 6]
```

If you can use `numpy`, it's very simple with the [`numpy.maximum()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) ufunc:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array([2, 4, 1, 6])
>>> arr2 = np.array([1, 5, 2, 3])
>>> np.maximum(arr1, arr2)
array([2, 5, 2, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick fix, in one set of iterations!

```
list_a = [2,4,1,6]
list_b = [1,5,2,3]

max_list = [value if list_b[index]<value else list_b[index] for index, value in enumerate(list_a)]

print(max_list)
```

Displays: `[2, 5, 2, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b = [10,20,30], [11,2,40]
c = [x if x > y else y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
```

Output: `[11,20,40]`

Answer (score -1):

Using List comprehension

```
l=[1,2,7]
m=[4,5,6]

max=[(l[i] if l[i]>m[i]  else m[i] ) for i in range(0,len(l))]
print(max)
```